# Hochschild (co)homology and Kahler differentials

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an augmented commutative algebra over a field $k$. What is the relation between Hochschild homology $H_n(A,k)$ and Kahler differential $\Omega_{A/k}$? The same question is also asked about $H^n(A,k)$ and $\Omega_{A/k}$. Here $k$ is considered as the trivial $A$-bimodule via the augmentation.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg+theorem

Comment: can HKR be globalised to schemes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xingting, I do not know the answer for your question. Nevertheless, the concepts involved in such questions are nicely developed in the following book (expressed in BibTex format):

@book {MR2640631,
    AUTHOR = {Majadas, Javier and Rodicio, Antonio G.},
     TITLE = {Smoothness, regularity and complete intersection},
    SERIES = {London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series},
    VOLUME = {373},
 PUBLISHER = {Cambridge University Press},
   ADDRESS = {Cambridge},
      YEAR = {2010},
     PAGES = {vi+134},
      ISBN = {978-0-521-12572-7},
   MRCLASS = {13D03 (13B10)},
  MRNUMBER = {2640631 (2011m:13028)},
MRREVIEWER = {Srikanth B. Iyengar},
       DOI = {10.1017/CBO9781139107181},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139107181},
}